# How to check two month are equal or not from date format YYYY-MM-DD?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have two dates like 2020-12-31 and 2020-12-01 in string format yyyy-mm-dd while check the month it should return true.

Suppose I compare 2020-11-31 and 2020-12-31 it should return false.

If there is a difference in only month and year, it should return true.

For example today Feb 18, 2020, Suppose I choose Feb 11, 2020, it should return true, If I choose Jan 11, 2020, then it should return false.

**Date difference should not be considered**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript ?

Comment: and date.getMonth()?

Comment: What should return 2020-11-31 and 2021-11-31? True or false? (Equal month is ambiguous)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Maheshwaran 
You can use something like this

```
var d1 = new Date("2020-12-31")
var d2 = new Date("2020-12-31")
return d1.getMonth() === d2.getMonth() && d1.getYear() === d2.getYear()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can go with the following code:

```
const date1 = new Date('2020-12-01');
const date2 = new Date('2020-12-31');

// if you want to return true or false based on either date or month or year difference then use the following code.

const diffTime = Math.abs(date2 - date1);
const diffDays = Math.ceil(diffTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)); 
// this way if there is difference in either date or month or year then it will return true
if(diffDays) {
  return true;
} else {
  return false;
}
```

If you want to return either true or false on basis of either month or year only then you can use the following code.

```
const date1 = new Date('2020-12-01');
const date2 = new Date('2020-12-31');
// return basis on difference of either month OR year 
return date1.getMonth() === date2.getMonth() || date1.getYear() === date2.getYear()

// return basis on the difference of month AND year
return date1.getMonth() === date2.getMonth() && date1.getYear() === date2.getYear()
```

Comment: suppose different year but same month it will work? like 2019-12-31 and 2020-12-31

Comment: @MaheswaranS  What's will work in your case? Should it return true or false then?

Comment: @MaheswaranS you have not asked about year difference in your question. You just asked about 2020-11-31 and 2020-12-31 i.e. If month not the same then it should return false.

Comment: @StackSlave I have updated the answer. by mistake, variables names were updated. :)

Comment: @ Deep Kakkar i want to check year also.

Comment: @MaheswaranS i.e. so now, if there is a difference in both dates or months or years then it should return true? right? If yes then let me update your question and then I will update my answer as well.

Comment: @ Deep there is difference in only month and year means it should return false. Date not an issue

Comment: For example today Feb 18, 2020, Suppose i choose Feb 11, 2020 it should return true, If i choose Jan 11, 2020 it should return false. I think you will get my question.

Comment: @MaheswaranS I have updated my answer. So now you can choose code snippet according to your requirement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208024/discussion-between-deep-kakkar-and-maheswaran-s).

Answer (score 0):

Shorted, faster, and simpler solution is:

```js
"2020-11-31".substr(5, 2) === "2020-12-31".substr(5, 2)
```